# Visual studio detect Ctrl+F5 and F5 mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any way that I can understand that my code is running with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>?

I wrote a GUI for an application for some students but it doesn't work some time when run it with <kbd>F5</kbd>...I want too detect <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> mode to disable GUI when user run it with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> runs the application without the debugger attached. You can tell if it was started with plain <kbd>F5</kbd> by checking the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached.

If the GUI sometimes breaks when run with a debugger attached, it is likely because you use multithreading incorrectly to access UI properties in a thread other than the main UI thread.

Comment: what should I include to use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached?
I tried windows.h but it still said its undefined

Comment: Thank you so much ...finally I used IsDebuggerPresent() in Windows.h

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached Property to tell if a debugger is attached or not, i assume that's what you mean.

Hope that helps

Paul